# Unix shell script to populate date from file as first column in the file

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, awk

1. I have a file name `abc.dat`, which consists the first record as below

   ```
   01|06/30/2020|test.txt.
   ```
2. The rest of the file contains records as

   ```
   123456|Alpha|....... 
   134567|Beta|.... 
   ................
   ```
3. Now from the file I need to take `06/30/2020` from the first record and convert it to `MMDDYYYY` format like `06302020` and place it as the first column in the file except for the first record.
4. Output: The output is expected as below

   ```
   01|06/30/2020|test.txt 
   06302020|123456|Alpha|..........
   06302020|134567|Beta|...........
   ................................
   ```
5. I tried with the following code

   ```bsh
   for file in `ls abc.dat`
   do
       #Gets filename for each row
       # echo "file = $file"
       rec=`wc -l $file`
       rec_cnt=`echo $rec | cut -f1 -d" "`
       #echo "Record Count = $rec_cnt"
       #extract the month end date from the first line from file
       month_end_date=`head -1 $file|tr -d '/'|cut -f2 -d"|"`
       #echo "month end date is $month_end_date"
       awk -F"|" '{if(NR == 1) printf ("%s\n",$0)
           else{ if ('$month_end_date' == $1) printf("%s\n",$0)
               else printf ("%s|%s\n",'$month_end_date',$0)} }'
   done
   ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please note that it is rarely necessary to call `awk` in a shell loop, as it can handle multiple files as command line arguments by itself. Also, looping over the *content* of a file and passing individual lines is extremely inefficient and therefore discouraged.

Actually, it is possible to implement the entire functionality as an `awk` program:

```
awk '
    BEGIN {OFS=FS="|"}
    FNR==1 {d=gensub("/","","g",$2); print;}
    FNR>1 {print d,$0}
' abc.dat
```

**Explanation:**

- On the first line of each file, this uses the `gensub()` function to create a copy of the second field (containing the date) where all `/` are replaced with the empty string (i.e. removed).
- On all later lines, this modified copy is prepended before the original line content.

Comment: thanks @AdminBee :-)

Comment: If your awk happens to not have gensub available, replace the FNR==1 line by `FNR==1 {print;gsub("/","",$2);d=$2}`.

Comment: I encountered new issue @pLumo, only able to get the desirable results when manually changing the permissions to 777, else it is not working as expected. I tried incorporating chmod 777 filename in the script. It is not working, every time I'm manually changing the file permissions.

Comment: Not sure I understand your problem. And I think it has nothing to do with your original question. So, please ask a new question refering to this one with as much information as possible.